Setting up the Client ID for Web application for Google Calendar API
I have a Flutter web app that usins the Google Calendar API to add events to the user's default Google calendar. If I run this locally on the localhost, it works perfectly. However, when I upload this to the production web server it doesn't seem to connect to the Google calendar.
I don't get any error but the event is not added to the calendar. I think it has to do with the way I have set up the Client ID for Web application in the Google Console.
This is the settings I have right now:

I think my problem is with the Authorized redirect URI. How do I know what this URI should be?
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.
